# Pass an instance property of a Groovy Server Pages to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

Here is the snippet of code:

```
<li>
    <g:link controller="Customer" action="customerInfo" id="${CustomerInstance.id}"  onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.customerInfo.confirm.message', default: 'Customer Info' ,args:['${CustomerInstance.id}'])}');">Customer Information</g:link>
</li>
```

What the code does is whenever a user clicks the link, an alert box should come with the customer id.

This code works for me:

```
<li>
    <g:link controller="Customer" action="customerInfo" id="${CustomerInstance.id}"   onclick="return confirm(Customer ID '+${CustomerInstance.id}+'.Are you sure to continue? ');">Customer Information</g:link>
</li>
```

I think there is something wrong with the quotes.Can somebody help me out??

Comment: The code that doesn't work:
<g:link controller="Customer" action="customerInfo" id="${CustomerInstance.id}"  onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.customerInfo.confirm.message', default: 'Customer Info' ,args:['${CustomerInstance.id}'])}');">Customer Information</g:link>

This code works for me:
<g:link controller="Customer" action="customerInfo" id="${CustomerInstance.id}"   onclick="return confirm(Customer ID '+${CustomerInstance.id}+'.Are you sure to continue? ');">Customer Information</g:link>


I think there is something wrong with the quotes.Can somebody help me out??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the single quotes or GSP expression in your 'args' parameter. You can just do the following:  args:[CustomerInstance.id]

Full example:

```
<li>
    <g:link controller="Customer" action="customerInfo" id="${CustomerInstance.id}"  onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'default.button.customerInfo.confirm.message', default: 'Customer Info' ,args:[CustomerInstance.id])}');">Customer Information</g:link>
</li>
```